# Online compiler with node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build an online compiler IDE and I always get an error that I can't understand or solve. the project/application consists of (index.html - package.json - app.js) the "app.js" refers to the server side which surely causes this error ("File not found: Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/Mr_Tech/Desktop/online_judge_system/compilecode"). this is the code:

```
// including all packages and modules that will be used
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var compiler = require('compilex');


// create a app variable for using express packages and body-parser
var app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

//Then initialize comiler options from compilex package and link "/" root page with the "index.html".
var option = {stats : true};
compiler.init(option);
app.get('/' , function (req , res ) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname +"/index.html");
});

// define the post funtion for the language you want your compiler to have and with input or without input options
app.post('\compilecode' , function (req , res ) {
    
    var code = req.body.code;   
    var input = req.body.input;
    var inputRadio = req.body.inputRadio;
    var lang = req.body.lang;
    if((lang === "C") || (lang === "C++"))
    {        
        if(inputRadio === "true")
        {    
            var envData = { OS : "windows" , cmd : "g++"};      
            compiler.compileCPPWithInput(envData , code ,input , function (data) {
                if(data.error)
                {
                    res.send(data.error);           
                }
                else
                {
                    res.send(data.output);
                }
            });
       }
       else
       {
        
        var envData = { OS : "windows" , cmd : "g++"};     
            compiler.compileCPP(envData , code , function (data) {
            if(data.error)
            {
                res.send(data.error);
            }       
            else
            {
                res.send(data.output);
            }
    
            });
       }
    }
    if(lang === "Java")
    {
        if(inputRadio === "true")
        {
            var envData = { OS : "windows" };     
            console.log(code);
            compiler.compileJavaWithInput( envData , code , function(data){
                res.send(data);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var envData = { OS : "windows" };     
            console.log(code);
            compiler.compileJavaWithInput( envData , code , input ,  function(data){
                res.send(data);
            });
        } 
    }       
    if( lang === "Python")
    {
        if(inputRadio === "true")
        {
            var envData = { OS : "windows"};
            compiler.compilePythonWithInput(envData , code , input , function(data){
                res.send(data);
            });            
        }
        else
        {
            var envData = { OS : "windows"};
            compiler.compilePython(envData , code , function(data){
                res.send(data);
            });
        }
    }

}); // end POST function 

// set the port for the server to listen and and define the get function to send the output data generated after the executed code to the server.
app.get('/fullStat' , function(req , res ){
    compiler.fullStat(function(data){
        res.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(8000);

// function to delete all the temporary files created during the process
compiler.flush(function(){
    console.log('All temporary files flushed !'); 
    });
```

Comment: If the code gets executed, this is a security risk. There are also existing (restricted and locked to a VM for safety) services you can use in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The problem is you are using a file:// path when this needs to be run as a HTTP server and you need to go to localhost:8000. You also used a backslash as a web path which is invalid.

Comment: it gives me this error : "Cannot POST /compilecode"

Comment: Because you used a \ in `\compilecode`, it should be app.post('/compilecode').

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved if that fixed it.